# compare lists and return common objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>();

            custList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P1" });
            custList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P2" });
            custList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P3" });
            custList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P4" });
            custList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P5" });

            List<Customer> vendorList = new List<Customer>();
            vendorList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P1" });
            vendorList.Add(new Customer { Name = "P2" });

            //var v = custList.SelectMany(


        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

How do i copare these 2 lists and find only those customers who are present in custList as well as vendorList?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a comment to another answer:

> Intersect expects both lists to be of
>   same type. What if they are not of
>   same type and what if property name is
>   different in both lists? How do i use
>   SelectMany here

In this case, you may wish to utilize `Join`. Such as

```
var result = from item1 in list1
             join item2 in list2
             on item1.Foo equals item2.Bar
             select new { item1, item2 }; // select whatever you need in the resultset
```

Comment: Is there any other way than manually joining them? Say I have a List<List<Customer>> where I want to find a common property value among List<Customer>?

Answer (score 13):

Ideally, make your `Customer` class override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (better yet, implement `IEquatable<Customer>`). Then you can just use:

```
var customerVendors = custList.Intersect(vendorList);
```

Otherwise, you'll to implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare customers for equality (e.g. by name, but you may choose other comparisons) and then use:

```
var customerVendors = custList.Intersect(vendorList, new CustomerComparer());
```

Note that these will both return `IEnumerable<Customer>`, which will be lazily evaluated. Sometimes that's what you want, but if you really need a `List<Customer>`, just call `ToList()` at the end, e.g.

```
var customerVendors = custList.Intersect(vendorList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

If your Customer class implements a "value like" `Equals()` you can just do:

```
var inbothLists = custList.Intersect(vendorList).ToList();
```

Otherwise you can use the overload that passes a custom `IEQualityComparer` that you can implement in a separate class (i.e. `CustomerComparer`) :

```
var inbothLists = custList.Intersect(vendorList, new CustomerComparer())
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Intersect expects both lists to be of same type. What if they are not of same type and what if property name is different in both lists? How do i use SelectMany here?

Comment: @Asdfg: Then you're talking about a different question, to be honest... and you'd use a Join.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var commonList = custList.Intersect(vendorList);
```

All you need is IEqualityComparer to compare based on Name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var both  = (from a  in custList 
             join b in vendorList on a.Name equals b.Name 
             select a);
```